# d3.js - D3 map not show up with China city dataset

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am building up a road map for a city called Shenzhen in China. I got the dataset from mapzen.com and convert the shape file to JSON file with topojson command line (topojson -o -p).

Here is my json file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MandyZou/Mandy-Web/gh-pages/ShenzhenMap/shenzhenroads.json

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Shenzhen Map</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3.0.0"></script>
</head>

<body>
<svg id="map" width ="500" height = "960"></svg>

<script>
    var margin = {top: 20, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20},
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 960 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#map")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.json, "shenzhenroads.json")
        .await(ready);

    function ready(error, data){
        if (error) throw error;

        console.log(data)

        var ShenzhenRoads = topojson.feature(data, {
            type: "GeometryCollection",
            geometries: data.objects.shenzhen_china_osm_roads.geometries
        });

        var projection = d3.geoMercator().center([23, 114]).scale(100).translate([width/2, height/2]);

        var path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        svg.select("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(ShenzhenRoads.features)
            .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "roads")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("fill", "#C5C5C5");
    };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it might due to the projection I used here... I tried d3.geoMercator, d3.geoTransverseMercator, and d3.geoEquirectangular, but none of them work...

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my map and how should I fix it? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to address two items to see your features.

**1. `svg.select("g")` does not select any element.**

When you define the variable svg you use:

```
var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

This will return a selection with the `g` element, not the `svg` element. For instance try:

```
console.log(svg.node()); // <g transform="translate(20,20)">
```

Instead, just use:

`svg.selectAll("path").data(....`

**2. Coordinates for .center, .rotate and in general in d3 are [x,y].**

You need to swap your coordinates here:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator().center([23, 114])...
```

To:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator().center([114, 23])...
```

3. **topojson.feature returns geojson,**

you can simplify this statement:

```
   var ShenzhenRoads = topojson.feature(data, {
        type: "GeometryCollection",
        geometries: data.objects.shenzhen_china_osm_roads.geometries
    });
```

to:

```
  var ShenzhenRoads = topojson.feature(data,  data.objects.shenzhen_china_osm_roads);
```

**Refinements**

Your zoom factor is way to small, your data may still be invisible (though it should be in the DOM), a scale factor of 200 000 might be more appropriate.

Second, you are using `.attr("fill","color")` for your paths, you probably don't want to fill the paths as this will make them look like polygons with one long straight section connecting the first and last points. Instead try:

```
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke","steelblue");
```

Using your data and the following projection (admittedly zoomed in too far):

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
 .center([114, 22.5])
 .scale(500000)
 .translate([width/2, height/2]);
```

I got this image:

[image]

Here is a [gist/block](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/b975cc3e4b0227b144f3279fdbb924b3) (I did not use queue.js, instead I used d3.json), using your dataset. This is dataset is atypically large for d3 - it might be worth looking into vector tiles (or raster tiles).

Comment: Hi @AndrewReid! Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! However, I changed my code but still nothing happened. Can you share your code with me so that I can cross-check mine? By the way, here is my updated script: https://github.com/MandyZou/Mandy-Web/blob/gh-pages/ShenzhenMap/shenzhen.html Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I must have missed modifications I made when convert the topojson to geojson - I've updated the answer, and everything should be visible in the bl.ock/gist example now at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your answer also helps me with my other problems! I really appreciate it!